# How to execute JS function after successfull ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, fullscreen

I want to demonstrate my window in a full screen.

I have a working function, but I have a problem:

I'm sending an AJAX call after user's click on some button in UI, to get some data and prepare it, after this ajax call (on `success` I want to demonstrate my data in the full screen, but I can't do that, because it raises an error:
`Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`

As you understand, I had user action - click on button, but it's not enough, if I' trying to execute `fullscreen function` in ajax call.

I was trying to use global variable too, to have a state(do I need to show fullscreen or not(it depends on result of response parsing(after AJAX call)), but it doesn't work too.I was trying in this way:

```
ISFULLSCREEN = false;

function get_ajax() {
    ajax_call ()
    .success(response) {
        if (response.fullscreen) {
           ISFULLSCREEN = true;
        }
    }
 }


function useFullscreen() {
    if (ISFULLSCREEN) {
        use_fullscreen();
    }
}
```

and my button looks like:

```
<button onclick="get_ajax();useFullscreen()" value="click me" />
```

but function `useFullscreen` runs faster, than the value of `ISFULLSCREEN` changes to `true`

Do somebody have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can call useFullscreen inside your success function.

Comment: @Avi They say in the question that it fails to execute

Comment: I can't, it raises the same error: "Failed to execute 'requestFullScreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.". It was my the first implementation

Comment: One suggestion is to put up another button that says something like "Best viewed fullscreen" and have user click that

Comment: @charlietfl, maybe, but I don't want to have a lot of buttons on UI

Comment: well you can't circumvent the time it takes for the ajax to complete

Comment: @pivanchy First have only `get_ajax()` binded to button and on response change the onclick function to `useFullScreen()` and trigger the new onclick event through code.

Comment: @Avi, it looks awful, but I can't see better ideas for now..

Comment: @Avi, hm....I'm running these commands:  `$('#previewBtn').unbind('click');$('#previewBtn').bind('click', function() { toggleFullScreen('preview_ad'); });$('#previewBtn').click();`, but it raises the same error again..

Comment: @pivanchy Could you try binding `touch` events instead of click.

Comment: @Avi, I'll try. I didn't know about this event

Comment: @Avi, I read about this event,  and as I understand,  it's fine for mobile apps, but I'm working with desktop application

Comment: @pivanchy Since you are using jquery you can make use of jquery fullscreen plugin itself with no work around.

Comment: @avi, additional plugins - additional dependencies=additional traffic, what is not so good, in case when there is an implementation without it, using HTML5

Comment: Add async : false to ajax call and call the function useFullscreen on ajax success and remove this from the button onclick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps in your ajax request, use `async: false` to make the fetch synchronous, therefore keeping all the execution within the same event (from the user click).

The downside to this is that it may hang the page if it takes a long time

Comment: it looks like a workaround, but not as a solution, unfortunately

Comment: The only other way I can think of is that when the user clicks the button, it instantly goes to fullscreen, and then you show some loading or please wait screen while the ajax goes off and completes its action

Comment: it's not a solution too, because I don't need to have a fullscreen mode always. I'm parsing a data from AJAX response, and after it I know: do I need a fullscreen or not..

Comment: The only other solution I can think of is that you call the AJAX before the button click, on some previous event before hand. I don't think there is any other way

Comment: I used async AJAX call, as I haven't too many data from server and it takes not too long. Other solutions were not very useful

Answer (score 1):

You can use `callback function`, **a callback function is a function passed into another function as an argument**, so you can utilize it, and it will execute after your awaited ajax response comes, see below example:

```
ISFULLSCREEN = false;

function get_ajax(useFullscreenCallback) {
    ajax_call ()
    .success(response) {
        if (response.fullscreen) {
           ISFULLSCREEN = true;
           useFullscreenCallback();
        }
    }
 }


function useFullscreen() {
    if (ISFULLSCREEN) {
        use_fullscreen();
    }
}

get_ajax(useFullscreen);
```

Reference: [Callback Function Mozilla web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?: [Run a website in fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281986/run-a-website-in-fullscreen-mode)

The answer basically says that you cannot force a fullscreen change without user interaction but there are some alternate suggestions

Comment: I was reading this article, but it doesn't help in my situation

Answer (score 0):

Add async : false to ajax call and call the function useFullscreen on ajax success and remove this from the button onclick event