# Browsing a web project in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a mobile web application, which is not populated on the internet and only accessible by a few persons. Problem is, that the adress bar is annoying for a few persons. They want that the application looks like a native app, without seeing the browser elements. I have tested a few things, the best way, which I have found is [Website in Fullscreen Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281986/run-a-website-in-fullscreen-mode/30970886#30970886). This works very fine for the first moment. After accepting fullscreen on login page, I can browse through the whole application, without losing the fullscreen mode. (Currently by pressing any key)

Problem is, when I switch to desktop and reopen the browser again, I will see again the login page and have to press any key that I get acutally the right view.  That's really confusing for the user. I have to switch to desktop, because the user have to interact with an android application. Could I avoid this in any way?

Or is there another way, that the fullscreen on mobile browser is still active, after starting an application and changing back to the browser? Also Okay, when the user have to make seperate browser settings for that.

Currently using Chrome Mobile Browser.

Comment: You could use PhoneGap or one of the many other frameworks that lets you convert web code to a native app.

Comment: But my whole backend is on a TomCat-Server, i dont wanna switch this structure.

Comment: You could create a hybrid android app, that opens a webview into the whole screen.